# Does setting IsAccessible to false on a button click stop or skip any coding?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to design a windows form app where when I click a button the button gets disabled and also wait cursor is shown just to indicate that the program is still running and then does all things that is assigned to the button click event and at the very last the button is enabled again.

This is my code

```
Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
button1.IsAccessible=false;

string path=textBox1.Text;
var files=Directory.GetFiles(path,"*.xml",SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach (var item in files)
{
    XDocument xdoc=XDocument.Load(item);
    xdoc.Descendants("title").First().Value="Resumen";
    xdoc.Descendants("source").First().Value="Apolpa";
    xdoc.Descendants("volume").First().Value="300";
    xdoc.Descendants("issue").First().Value="XXV";
    xdoc.Descendants("label").First().Value="[1]";
    xdoc.Save(item);
}

MessageBox.Show("Complete!");
button1.IsAccessible=true;
```

My question is since I've added `button1.IsAccessible=false;` at the very beginning of the code (before any modification is done to the files), will it skip or not properly run all the codes in the button click event?

This might be a stupid question but I'm new to this and I just wanted to know for sure...Thanks

Comment: The problem is, you're doing all of your work on the UI thread so your form never gets an opportunity to repaint itself whilst you're working. Also, `IsAccessible` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever then how do I do what I'm trying?

Comment: [`IsAccessible`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.isaccessible(v=vs.110).aspx): "Gets or sets a value indicating whether the control is visible to accessibility applications."

Answer (score 0):

You can use `button1.Enabled=false;` instead of `button1.IsAccessible=false;` and `button1.Enabled=true;` instead of `button1.IsAccessible=true;` and keep the `Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor` as it is.

Additionally, I would prefer using a **Progressbar** in a situation like this.
Check the code below:

```
Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
button1.Enabled=false;
//set the starting value of progressBar to 0
progressBar1.Minimum=0;

string path=textBox1.Text;
var files=Directory.GetFiles(path,"*.xml",SearchOption.AllDirectories);
//set the max value of progressBar to the no. of files
progressBar1.Maximum = files.Length;

foreach (var item in files)
{
    //the value of the progressBar increases by +1 for each file
    progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Value+1;

    XDocument xdoc=XDocument.Load(item);
    xdoc.Descendants("title").First().Value="Resumen";
    xdoc.Descendants("source").First().Value="Apolpa";
    xdoc.Descendants("volume").First().Value="300";
    xdoc.Descendants("issue").First().Value="XXV";
    xdoc.Descendants("label").First().Value="[1]";
    xdoc.Save(item);
}

MessageBox.Show("Complete!");
button1.Enabled=true;
```